# print int value or convert int to string in C language

Tags: c

I tried to print integer value, But It's print only `result is`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(i % 2 == 0){
      printf("result is \n","%d",i);
  }
}
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this way. It's not print anything

```
int main()
{
char buffer[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(i % 2 == 0){
      snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", i);
  }
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings. Also, read the documentation for both `printf` and `snprintf`.

Comment: Minimally, remove the comma in `\n","%d`, but better rewrite the format as `"result is %d\n"`.  Using `snprintf()` formats the string (10 is marginal for the length of the buffer for general integers, but adequate for values 1..10); you still need to print the resulting string (`printf("%s\n", buffer);`).  You could use `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)` which would save you testing for even values (it only generates even values).

Comment: I am very beginning to learn program.. I learn what it is -`-wall -wextra`

Comment: I tried with vs code..Is it good for C?

Comment: The options `-Wall` and `-Wextra` are (a) case-sensitive and (b) specific to GCC and Clang — two popular compilers.  They provide extra warnings compared to omitting those options.  There probably is an analogue in VS Code — it might be `-W3` or `-W4` (or `/W3` or `/W4`) or something similar; I think `W3` is valid, but I'm not sure about `W4` and I've not used it on Linux etc so I don't know which character to use before options.

Comment: Unless something dramatic has happened, VS Code only supports C90, which is a standard that's almost 30 years old and has been superseded by C99, C11 and C18 (though C11 and C18 are extremely similar).  If you're working on Linux or other Unix-like systems, then VS Code may not be the best choice.  If you're primarily working on Windows but want to compile for Linux etc too, maybe it works.  (Again, I've not used it on Unix-like systems — I've seen Visual Studio at work on Windows, and it is a confounded nuisance that I can't use C99 features because the code has to port to Unix and Windows.)

Comment: You could also use `puts(buffer);` to output the formatted buffer with a newline at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` should not be a separate parameter to `printf` but part of the template.

Try

```
printf("result is %d\n",i);
```

With your second example, you use:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", i);
```

It works by wiring the integer as a string to your buffer char array, not to the console (as per documentation).
Adding the line after the snprintf line:

```
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

You could print the content of your buffer to the screen.